# Draw a set of values in complex plane where the complex number $w=1-3i$ is pure imaginary number.

Tags: complex-numbers

How would you draw a set of values (in complex plane) where the complex number $w=1-3i$ is pure imaginary number?

Could this be the solution? If $Rew=0$.

[image]

Comment: What does "the complex number $1 - 3i$ is imaginary" mean?

Comment: The set must show where the complex number $w$ is only imaginary.

Comment: $1 - 3i$ is constant. It's not imaginary in some regions and real in some regions and complex in other regions. Could you tell us where you saw the question, and what exactly the statement is?

Comment: I wish I could tell you the exact statement, but It was in an exam and I have never seen a similar task before. That is why I posted this question here. But I still remember it very well - it was saying that we need to draw a set of values in complex plane, where the complex number $w$ is only imaginary. That was the task, that's all, but I had no idea how to draw that.

Comment: $w=1-3i$ is a constant. Re$(w)=1$ and Im$(w)=-3$. It is not clearly imaginary (as it has nonzero real part). Maybe it is about $w^s$ for some real exponent $s$???

Comment: Your number $w$ is imaginary whenever $1=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If you speak about "set of values", I think to something that moves, like a function, not something stationary, as a number.

Hence you can substitute your number with the following function
$$
w=w(t)=t-3i
$$
that is an horizontal line, passing thru the point $(0,-3)$ (once you see $\mathbb C$ as the real plane $\mathbb R^2$).

Then the question "when does $w$ is imaginary?" makes sense.

By definition a complex number $a+ib$ is imaginary iff its real part is zero, i.e when $a=0$. So looking at $w(t)=t-3i$, the set of values where the complex number $w(t)$ is imaginary is where $t=0$, i.e. $w(0)=-3i$ that is the point you draw in your picture.

Comment: I am sorry, but where did you see "when does w is imaginary"?

Comment: "How would you draw a set of values (in complex plane) where the complex number $w=1−3i$ is pure imaginary number?" is equivalent to asking "when does $w$ is imaginary?"

Comment: This was my interpretation, the unique that makes sense, to me.

Comment: I am really sorry for that. I am still an english learner, but I try really hard to write everything correctly.